# adding cookie to a flask function that returns a redirect

Tags: python, flask, cookies

The flask documentation for [setting a header](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.make_response) suggests the following:

```
def index():
    response = make_response(render_template('index.html', foo=42))
    response.headers['X-Parachutes'] = 'parachutes are cool'
    return response
```

I wish to set a cookie which can be done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46664792/9727704):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template(...))
    resp.set_cookie('somecookiename', 'I am cookie')
    return resp
```

However, my function returns a redirect:

```
@app.route('/applications', methods=['POST'])
def create_application():

    data = request.get_json()

    try: 
        application = Application(
            'foo' : 'bar'
        )
        db.session.add(application) 
        db.session.commit()

        # set a cookie with application.id here

        return redirect('/application/'+str(application.id), code=302)
```

According to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.redirect) `redirect` only accepts a location, not a response object.

There is the `@app.after_response` decorator, which will run after every request is processed, but how do I get info from my `application` object to it? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the function `redirect()` ([linked here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.redirect)), it also returns a response object similar to the function `make_response()`.

So you could do something like the following code to get your expected result.

```
@app.route('/applications', methods=['POST'])
def create_application():

data = request.get_json()

try: 
    application = Application(
        'foo' : 'bar'
    )
    db.session.add(application) 
    db.session.commit()

    # Create a redirect Reponse object
    redirected_response = redirect('/application/'+str(application.id), code=302)

    # set a cookie with application.id here
    redirected_response.set_cookie('appidcookie', f'{application.id}')
    
    # return the redirected response
    return redirected_response
```

Comment: What version of Flask are you using? It doesn't seem to work for me with Flask 2.1.3 .

Comment: I have linked the documentation for version 2.2.x, so you can give it a try using Flask 2.2.

Comment: Actually, the problem was elsewhere, this works fine.